# Ant command run problems

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

So i am having trouble running my project via the ant build.xml file. The project runs

perfectly when executed normally, image link posted below:

http://puu.sh/75krJ.png

However, when the project is ran through a build.xml file, it produces this error below:

[code]

```
  <description>
    Ant Build File for myproj0/
  </description>

  <!-- Property Names -->
  <property name="src" location="src" />
  <property name="build" location="build" />
  <property name="main.class" value="driver.Driver"/>
  <property name="doc" location="doc" />

  <!-- initializes the program -->
  <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${src}"/> 
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compiles source code">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="run" description="Runs the main">
    <java dir="${build}" classname="${main.class}" fork="yes" >
      <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${build}" />
      </classpath>
     </java>
  </target>

  <target name="clean" description="Deletes the created directories">
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="bin"/>
    <delete dir="doc"/>
  </target>

  <target name="doc" description="Generates the Javadoc" depends="compile">
    <javadoc sourcepath="${src}" destdir="${doc}" />
  </target>

</project>
```

[/code]

Error:

http://puu.sh/75kRy.png

I am refraining from posting my assignment code due to others from school probably looking at this site for help as well

Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: Post text, not images; come on. Obviously the directory you're running from is different in the two cases, and the file cannot be found.

Comment: post your ant script too

Comment: I apologize. I didn't want anyone to say that im asking someone to do my homework for them

Comment: I don't think posting links to images instead of text is really the differentiating factor regarding homework. Besides, I already told you what's wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton - DownVoting my answer really doesn't help me. Would you mind explaining where the 2 different directories thing is happening?

Comment: @user2128074 Take up downvotes with whoever downvoted. "Where" it's happening? Between the two environments. We don't know how (a) your IDE is set up, or (b) how you're running via the ant script. These things matter.

Comment: @DaveNewton - What would you like to know about my IDE? I am running Via eclipse, i generated an ant build file by right clicking on project then exporting, that generated an ant build file. I am running that build file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ant` script compiles the java classes and puts them into the `build` directory (that's how it should be). This happens in the target named compile. I assume you have put your input file into the `src` folder in Eclipse. Eclipse also has a build directory - usually `bin` - and copies such files over automtically. (There are filters in the settings which define the file types it won't copy.)

The `ant` script does not copy the input file. So it cannot be found, when run from the ant script, but it is found when run from Eclipse.

To copy the input file, add this to the compile target:

```
  <copy todir="${build}">
     <fileset dir="${src}" includes="*.txt" />
  </copy>
```

This copies all `.txt` files from the src directory to the build directory.

(Note: As mentioned, I assume your text file is in the source directory. If it is not, this is probably not the correct solution.)